# Can't join three tables and return all records from just one

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am using, but very new to, SQL Server Express 2012 and SS Management Studio and databases in general.
Despite much time and research, I cannot quite achieve my goal with a particular stored procedure and can't move on without some advice.

I want to retrieve data from three related Tables A, B and C.
I want to have all rows from TableA and only the relevant rows from tables TableB and TableC (if they exist).

I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226912/join-three-tables) on StackOverflow which was the closest match to my problem, which I have tried without success.  The code snippet is as follows:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM
  (TableA A LEFT JOIN TableB B ON A.id = B.a_id)
  LEFT JOIN TableC C ON A.id = C.a_ID
```

Now, this code has the related "ID" fields for TableB (B.a_id) and TableC (C.a_id) BOTH related to TableA (A.id).

In my case, TableA is related to TableB and TableC is related to TableB.  It is all records from TableA that I want returned with just a couple of 'descriptive' fields from the other two tables for each of the TableA records.
I am returning more records than I require so how do I filter the output to just the records in TableA?

Can anyone suggest what I should do to resolve this please.

**IMPORTANT EDIT**

Sorry everyone - just to clarify from reading your excellent responses..

I JUST want to return ALL rows in TableA ONLY.  I am including TableB and TableC just to return appropriate columns for each of these rows.

**FURTHER INFO EDIT**

In simple terms my context is similar to this:

TableA is a table of Employees.  It has two columns: EmployeeID, EmployeeName

TableB is a table of Depts.  It has three columns DeptID, DeptName, EmployeeID

TableC is a table of Firms.  It has three columns FirmID, FirmName, DeptID

I want a list of all Employees (i.e. all rows in TableA) to put into a listbox (in Excel VBA) from which the user can select.  In the listbox I would want to show the user respective columns from TableB and TableC:

EmployeeID, EmployeeName, FirmName, DeptName

I am looking for the logic and query code to achieve this

Comment: you mention rows, but then say you just need a couple of fields from the other two tables - so, you must be talking about columns? If you, you have not specified which columns you need. Your query (so far) just says return everything from A (A.*)

Comment: You can still do : select a.*, c.desc from tablea a left join tableb b on a.id = b.id left join tablec c on b.subid = c.subid

Comment: a.* means you will only grab from table A. I'm not sure what other results you're looking for please edit your question and try again.

Comment: @Mathese F I have tried this but still return more records than in TableA.

Comment: @Zane Forget the A.* this was just the example.  I can return all the columns I need from all three tables BUT I only want rows to be returned that are in TableA.  At present I am returning more rows than this.

Comment: @Roberto Yes I have specified the columns I require in my own SELECT statement.  The A.* was the general case specified in the example which, for brevity, I just left.  I can return the columns I need, I am just returning too many rows.

Comment: Then you want to `INNER JOIN` not `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Thank you @Zane, I have tried both JOIN and INNER JOIN but I am still returning more rows than in TableA.  See also response to xxMUROxx below

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results. Your description of the problem is way TL;DR.

Comment: @barryleajo You are getting more records because one of your `JOIN`ed tables contains multiple values for the `JOIN` key.  If you have an Id of `1` in `TableA` and two rows with an ID of `1` in `TableB` then you will get back 2 rows with that ID in your result set no matter what kind of join you use.

Comment: Do a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLEA` then do a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableA INNER JOIN TABLEB ON A.ID = B.ID INNER JOIN TABLEC ON A.ID = C.ID` or whatever your query is. What are the counts?

Comment: @Zane thank you.  As per comment to xxMUROxx below the 'stats' are TableA = 4 rows, TableB = 3 rows, TableC = 3 rows and I am returning 7 rows from the query.  My context is calling this query/sproc from Excel VBA in order that the results will populate a VBA listbox, from which the user can make a selection.  I want to return all the rows from TableA and some further column information for each of these rows from Tables B and C.  Pretty standard fare I would have thought yet it's starting to seem pretty complicated.

Comment: If you have a row in Employees with EmployeeID = 123 and two rows in Depts with the same EmployeeID, which of the two should be chosen for the output? What criterion/criteria should be used to determine that? For, if you return both Depts rows, the Employees row will be returned twice.

Comment: For my context Employee will only belong to one Dept/Firm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you join tables, you won't get records from different tables in separate rows, you fetch data from all the tables into the same result row.

Just include the fields that you want from the tables in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT
  A.*,
  B.Something,
  C.Something
FROM
  TableA A
  LEFT JOIN TableB B ON A.id = B.a_id
  LEFT JOIN TableC C ON A.id = C.a_ID
```

Note that you will always get a value for the `TableB` and `TableC` tables, i.e. the result is always the same number of columns. If there is no corresponding records from `TableB` or `TableC`, that field in the result will be `null`.

(Note also; using `*` in the `SELECT` is not good practice for actual application code. You should specify the fields that you want from the A table in the final code.)

#### Edit:

If you have more than one record in `TableB` or `TableC` for each record in `TableA`, and still only want one record in the result, you have to decide what to do with the multiple values from `TableB` or `TableC`.

To handle that you would group on the values from `TableA` and use aggregates on the values from `TableB` and `TableC`. For example getting the sum of the `Count` fields from `TableA` and the average of the `Price` fields from `TableB`:

```
SELECT
  A.Id,
  A.Name,
  SUM(B.Count) TotalCount,
  AVG(C.Price) AveragePrice
FROM
  TableA A
  LEFT JOIN TableB B ON A.id = B.a_id
  LEFT JOIN TableC C ON A.id = C.a_ID
GROUP BY
  A.Id,
  A.Name
```

Comment: thank you.  I can return all the columns I need using your syntax.  My problem is that I am returning too many rows - see Important edit in original post.  I want only to return rows from TableA.

Comment: @barryleajo: Well this *is* the way to do what you want *as you expressed it* in your question. If you get too many rows (i.e., as I understand it, more than what TableA has), then most likely what happens is this: a row in TableA has more than one match in either TableB or TableC. That causes the TableA row to be repeated in the output, one instance per each match. You need to decide which of the other table's (or tables') matched rows should end up in the output if you don't want the TableA data to be duplicated.

Comment: @barryleajo: If you have multiple values from TableB or TableC, you need to decide what to do with them. See my edit above.

Comment: @Andriy M thank you.  The reason I want just TableA rows to be returned is to populate a selection Listbox. Could you suggest a means of 'filtering' the current output or is there a 'standard' way in SQL of indicating 'just the rows from TableA'?

Comment: @barryleajo: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you are talking about. If you need "just the rows from TableA", select just the TableA rows. If you need to include data from other tables where matched, you need to first resolve the issue of *multiple matches* per TableA row (which of the matches to include), and I believe Guffa has just offered one way of solving that issue. If that doesn't work for you, please elaborate in your question, with examples, what you want exactly.

Comment: Thank you for your code suggestion.  However my data is largely type varchar with only ID no's as type int; so no calculations, no aggregations and I don't even want to count anything.

Comment: @Andriy M - further edit and example to my original question as suggested

Comment: @barryleajo: Which of the firm names and department names do you want to show?

Comment: For my context Employee will only belong to one Dept/Firm, so those that relate to each record in TableA

Comment: @barryleajo: If the are only related to one firm and one department, then you won't get more rows in the result than there are in `TableA`.

Comment: Thanks to your prompting I think I have found it!  The DeptID is only unique when paired with a FirmID. There were multiple occurrences of the same DeptID which were giving the expanded result set.  I changed the INNER JOIN on Dept to also include the FirmID and voila. I didn't realise you could join on multiple columns.  With apols to all for the scrappy Q and I'll take the -1 on the chin and do better next time.  Thanks also to @Andriy M; I can now move on.

Answer (score 0):

In the example SQL you have the following relationship diagram `TableC => TableA <= TableB` but you have following: `TableA <= TableB <= TableC`. So you have to write it as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1 
    JOIN TableB t2 ON t1.Id = t2.a_Id
    JOIN TableC t3 ON t2.Id = t3.b_Id
```

Comment: Thank you @xxMUROxx,  my table relationships are actually TableA => TableB => TableC which I think is probably the same(?) I am returning the correct columns, my problem is that I am returning too many rows.

Comment: In this example it is the same, but it wouldn't if you use `LEFT JOIN`s.
What do you mean with too many rows?

Comment: Thank you.  I have 4 rows in TableA, 3 rows in TableB and 3 rows in TableC.  I am returning 7 rows when I only want to return the 4 rows in TableA.  I am using the columns in Tables B and C just to provide descriptions for the rows in TableA which contain ID nos.

Comment: How does your sql query look like?

Comment: SET @sql = N'SELECT c.cRef, b.bRef, a.aID, a.aType, a.aRef1, a.aRef2 
FROM (TableA a JOIN TableB b ON a.aID = b.b_ID1) 
 JOIN TableC c ON b.b_ID2 = c.c_ID '