# Get The Last Process Of Each Job And Identify Status

Tags: mysql, sql

How to get the last step of a certain job and identify if the status of the last process of every job is equal to 1. If the status of the last process is equal to one then display the value.

JOB TABLE (prepressjobs)

```
+-----------+--------------+------------+
|    ID     | SchedNum     |  Item Name | 
+-----------+--------------+------------+
| 1         | JITE7ERUK    | Item 1     | 
| 2         | JV7FSW26Y    | Item 2     | 
| 3         | JQFXV4H3X    | Item 3     | 
+-----------+--------------+------------+
```

OPERATION TABLE (operation)

```
+-----------+--------------+------------+-----------+----------+
|    ID     | SchedNum     |  Job Name  |   Step    |  Status  |
+-----------+--------------+------------+-----------+----------+
| 1         | JITE7ERUK    | Designing  | 0         | 1        |
| 2         | JITE7ERUK    | Sample     | 1         | 1        |
| 3         | JITE7ERUK    | Printing   | 2         | 0        |
| 4         | JV7FSW26Y    | Designing  | 0         | 1        |
| 5         | JV7FSW26Y    | Sample     | 1         | 0        |
| 6         | JQFXV4H3X    | Designing  | 0         | 1        |
| 7         | JQFXV4H3X    | Sample     | 1         | 1        |
+-----------+--------------+------------+-----------+----------+
```

MY QUERY

```
SELECT *
FROM operation p1
INNER JOIN prepressjobs 
ON prepressjobs.pj_schednum = p1.operation_schednum 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT MAX(operation_step) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(operation_schednum) FROM operation )p2)
AND p1.operation_status = 0 ;
```

EXPECTED RESULT

```
+-----------+--------------+------------+-----------+----------+
| 7         | JQFXV4H3X    | Sample     | 1         | 1        |
+-----------+--------------+------------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: Is it mysql or MS SQL ?

Comment: @Aparna, mySQL.

Comment: @Aparna . It it most likely getting the last row like  using this code `SELECT m1.*
FROM operation m1 LEFT JOIN operation m2
ON (m1.operation_schednum = m2.operation_schednum AND m1.operation_id < m2.operation_id)
WHERE m2.operation_id IS NULL
;` but I need also to get if the `operation_status` is equal to 1.

Comment: Just posted the code in SQL Server ...Try converting that to @mysql

Comment: Igoes to an error. sql esyntax

Comment: @Aparna . I'm still on query and I'm on test now. I'm using this `SELECT m1.*
FROM operation m1 LEFT JOIN operation m2
ON (m1.operation_schednum = m2.operation_schednum AND m1.operation_id < m2.operation_id)
LEFT JOIN prepressjobs ON (prepressjobs.pj_schednum = m2.operation_schednum )
WHERE m1.operation_status=1
AND m2.operation_id IS NULL
;` and I just need now to join the prerpressjobs table. Can you help me?

Comment: Looks like mysql does not have the row_number() functions as in other dbs please read the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347565/how-to-get-a-row-rank which might throw some light .Sorry for not being to help here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151231/discussion-between-ailyn-and-aparna).

Comment: The query you posted works fine for me.Cant join in chat...access restricted

Comment: Sorry @Ailyn,chat.stackoverflow is blocked at my workplace .

Comment: @Aparna.Finally I got it. `SELECT *
FROM operation m1 
LEFT  JOIN operation m2 ON (m1.operation_schednum = m2.operation_schednum AND m1.operation_id < m2.operation_id)
LEFT  JOIN  prepressjobs m3 ON m1.operation_schednum = m3.pj_schednum
WHERE m1.operation_status=1
AND m2.operation_id IS NULL
;
`

Comment: ,thank you for letting me know this .Great to see you could uncover this yourself....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it on my own. But still thanks to @Aparna for respons. In addition I've got an idea at [Retrieving the last record in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group?rq=1) and [JOIN three tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226912/join-three-tables).

QUERY:

```
SELECT * FROM operation t1
INNER JOIN prepressjobs 
ON prepressjobs.pj_schednum = t1.operation_schednum 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM operation p2 WHERE p2.operation_step =   IF((t1.operation_step - 1)=-1,0,(t1.operation_step - 1) ) AND p2.operation_status = 1)
AND t1.operation_processname ='SINGLE DIELINE'
AND t1.operation_status = 0
AND prepressjobs.pj_status ='APPROVED'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below.This works in SQL Server

```
 select * from 
 (
 select *,row_number() over(partition by schednum order by step desc ) as rn 
 from operations 
 ) a 
 where a.rn=1 and a.status=1;
```